# Moving a vendor module to new cron group in magento 2

Tags: magento2, overrides, crontab, magento-cron

We are utilizing the Firebear module to import product and pricing data which run in the default cron group. The import takes quite a bit of time/resources so it was recommended to move the Firebear cron to its own group. The Firebear crontab.xml is currently setup like so:

```
vagrant/tmp/vendor/firebear/importexport/etc/crontab.xml
```

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
    <job name="importexport_jobs_run_id" instance="Firebear\ImportExport\Cron\RunImportJobs" method="execute">
    <schedule>*/1 * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
    <job name="importexport_export_jobs_run_id" instance="Firebear\ImportExport\Cron\RunExportJobs" method="execute">
        <schedule>*/1 * * * *</schedule>
    </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

At a high level I will need to:
1 - create new cron group
2 - override Firebear crontab to run in new group

Any help on the process to accomplish this will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on existing posts because i'm missing reputation or something like that, so i'm going to do it this way for the sake of clarity.

Aren't the last 2 steps, in guerinteed_mike's answer, just for Magento Cloud? To my knowledge, they use the .magento.app.yml file for configuring the server environment on their own hosting platform.

Comment: Yes, this was used on a Magento Clooud instance

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to update your answer then? Other users not having the cloud edition might be confused by the last steps. Or is there anything i missed within this topic that is restricted to cloud only?

Comment: Updated. Note - sometimes some aspects are not known when learning something new.

Comment: I didn't mean to be harsh or anything but just noticed it and thought it could be clarified. Thanks for updating! :)

Answer (score 1):

Create the new Cron Group and Cronjob as explained by guerinteed_mike.

Now to disable the crojob from the default group you can override the same in your custom file. This will avoid executing the default cron.

```
<group id="default">
    <job name="importexport_export_jobs_run_id" instance="Firebear\ImportExport\Cron\RunExportJobs" method="execute">
        <schedule>0 0 30 2 *</schedule>
    </job>
</group>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I used for a Magento 2.2 commerce instance hosted on Adobe Cloud.

Create a new module or add to an existing:

1 - New Cron Group

```
[module]/etc/cron_group.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/cron_groups.xsd">
    <group id="new_cron_group_name">
        <schedule_generate_every>1</schedule_generate_every>
        <schedule_ahead_for>4</schedule_ahead_for>
        <schedule_lifetime>2</schedule_lifetime>
        <history_cleanup_every>10</history_cleanup_every>
        <history_success_lifetime>120</history_success_lifetime>
        <history_failure_lifetime>600</history_failure_lifetime>
        <use_separate_process>1</use_separate_process>
    </group>
</config>
```

2 - create new crontab.xml or add jobs to existing:

```
[module]/etc/crontab.xml

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="new_cron_group_name">
        <job name="cron_job_name" instance="Magento\SomeModule\Cron\SomeJob" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

3 - add the new cron group to .magento.app.yml

```
...
crons:
    ...
    newcrongroupname:
        spec: "* * * * *"
        cmd: "php bin/magento cron:run --group='new_cron_group_name'"
```

4 - remove the crontab.xml from the vendor module via deploy hooks in .app.magento.yml:

```
...
hooks:
    # We run build hooks before your application has been packaged.
    build: |
        set -e
        rm -f vendor/modulename/importexport/etc/crontab.xml
        php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools build:generate
        php ./vendor/bin/ece-tools build:transfer
...
```

My understanding is that #4 could also be done via a patch.